Forecast based on SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR + last 3 month Moving Average
I decided to update this question with a better example.
You can download the sample files here:

Forecast.pbix
Forecast.xlsx

SCENARIO
I'm trying to create a forecast based on the last year's data and the Moving Average. As you can see I'm putting a different weight factor for each measure involved:

Cost2YearsAgo =  0.4
CostLastYear = 0.6

The result looks quite correct but I'm not happy with the forecast curve: given the last 3 months it should bend much lower:

PROBLEM
So I'm going to add the Moving Average and things tourn immediately sour:

Cost2YearsAgo =  0.3
CostLastYear = 0.5
MovingAverage = 0.1


I've been on rollercoasters that made puke less when I was younger.
SOLUTION
So I now try a different approach:

Cost2YearsAgo =  0.3
CostLastYear = 0.5
ThisYear= 0.1


This time it looks better but I'm not convinced by the logic.
How can the actuals of the first months of 2024 affect the future forecast?
The data are not rolling in the future.

Why the MovingAverage  is not working?
And how can the ThisYear fix the problem and affect the curve in the future?

